# is setRegion inconsistent between iOS versions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mapkit

I developed a game some time ago.
The game consists on a map of spain, and you have to guess where a city is on that map (I have EEUU and china versions too)
I developed all of them with iOS 5 base, and using iOS 5 sdk.

Then, 3 weeks ago I updated the spanish game and I had to use the iOS 6 sdk, all seems fine on the simulator and on my ipad 2 (iOS 5.0.1) and iPod touch (iOS 5.1) and released the update.

But when people started downloading or updating the new version, some of them contacted me because the map didn't fit to the screen.

this is the screenshot of how do I see the game on my devices and simulator. (iPad 5.0.1 and simulator with 5.0, 6.0 and 6.1, in both retina and normal mode)
[image: right]

this is a screenshot of how does it shown on other people devices. (iPad 3 with iOS 6.0 and iPad 2 with iOS 6.0.1 )

[image: wrong]

This is my code for iPad (as far as I know, on iPhone is working as expected)

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerLocation;
MKCoordinateRegion region;
centerLocation.latitude = 39.016740;
centerLocation.longitude = -5.93504;
region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerLocation, 0, 800000);
[map setRegion:region];
```

at first I thought it was a retina issue, because the first person who contacted my was using an iPad 3, I fixed the map for iPad retina on monday, but yesterday I got the same message from another user with an iPad 2.

So, am I doing something wrong?
is setRegion inconsistent between iOS versions?
how can I test my code if it works fine on simulators?

Can somebody try my code on real devices and tell me if they get the map like the first one or the second one?

**EDIT1:**
Final thoughts after accepting the answer:
This wasn't an problem between iOS versions, it appears to be a timing problem, the region is different if you set it before the view appears or after.
It happens in both, iOS 5 and iOS 6.

The only difference between iOS 5 and iOS 6 happens on real devices, if you set the region before the map appears, it stays as it is, but on iOS 6 on the simulator it will remain as it is, but on the real device, it will be displayed as the region setted when the view appears.

So, the solution is setting the region on `viewDidAppear` and it will be displayed the same way on iOS 5 and iOS 6, on simulators and real devices.

**EDIT 2:**
it seems the 0 on the region had something to do with the problem too, if I use `region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerLocation, 800000, 800000);` the region is the same before and after the view load, at least on the simulator. 
If I use `region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerLocation, 0, 800000);` the region is different if I use it before the view loads, and appears "zoomed" when I use it later.

I'll wait until I receive my iPad retina with iOS6 to continue testing this issue.

Comment: In my case, I could not get span to work correctly until I set 'animated:NO' on setRegion. If I set animated:YES, iOS 6 seems to ignore the span. Did not have this issue with iOS 5 or prior.

Comment: Have you solved it? Whatever I do it does not set the precise region that I want in iphone4 ios6.1.3

Comment: Setting the region on viewDidAppear worked in my case. But regions on ios aren't precise, I was lucky that there were regions that fit the spain map on iphone with 3.5" screens and ipad, but there isn't a region that fits the spain map on iphone 5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There a few important differences in the way regions work in iOS 5 and 6. On iOS 5, the region that you ask to be set will rarely be the actual region that gets set. This is to do with MapKit on iOS 5 always setting a region that allows the tile images to be displayed at a 1:1 ratio. On iOS 6, there are no tile images and everything is drawn from vector data, so the region that you get is very close to the region that you ask for.

That being said, I think the problem with your code might be the timing. I could reproduce your problem when I set the map's region in `viewDidLoad:`, even when I used a proper span (instead of using `0` for the latitude delta). When I moved the code to `-viewDidAppear:`, the region set properly on an iPad with iOS 6, as well as the Simulator with iOS 6. Here's the code I used:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerLocation = 
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.016740, -5.93504);
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(12.7, 12.7);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerLocation, span);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
}
```

I used `12.7` as the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`. It's good to make the region a square to that the region will have the important places in landscape and portrait mode. You'll need to import the Core Location framework if you want to use the `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake()` function.

So I think that the problem is that MapKit is setting the region after you try to set it (on iOS 6). You can check the region being set in `-mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` with the following code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", 
            self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta, 
            self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta, 
            self.mapView.region.center.latitude, 
            self.mapView.region.center.longitude);
}
```

So, if your code is setting the region in `-viewDidLoad:`, try moving it to `-viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: I'll check my code, but I'm pretty sure I changet it to viewDidAppear and nothing changed. Are you using autoLayouts? Because I noticed this on a test I made, and it was only happening when autolayout was selected

Comment: One way to check whether it's a timing issue is to set your region on a button press. Make a custom action and wait until everything is loaded, then tap the button.

Comment: you were right, I had the code on viewWillAppear, not on viewDidAppear.

Comment: I still don't understand why on the simulator it works as I expect, but not on real devices, but at least now, I can know how the map will be displayed on the real device changing the code to viewDidAppear, so I accept your answer and assign the bounty

Comment: I don't really understand it myself, and I always used to use `-viewDidLoad:` for setting up the map without problems. I think that some timing things have changed in iOS 6, there was a difference in how annotations were loading too. I kind of sounds like a bug, you might want to report it in the bug tracker.

Comment: `So, if your code is setting the region in -viewDidLoad:, try moving it to -viewDidAppear:.` This saved my day, now I can use AutoLayout!

Comment: Does your solution woke in ios6 simulator, too?

Answer (score 2):

Your coordinate region is very strange — I wouldn't be surprised if MapKit was ignoring it completely.

The centre of (39.016740, -5.93504) looks fine but you're stating that, ideally, your view would show 0 metres of latitude (ie, would have zero height) and 800 km of longitude.

Have you tried supplying a sensible latitude value?

Comment: Might also want to look at `-[MKMapView regionThatFits:]` and see what it gives you; might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have the same problem if I use region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerLocation, 800000, 800000); The region is created fitting the biggest to the screen, so there is no difference between 0 and 800000

Comment: And the problem I have is, it works fine on iOS 5 devices, and it works fine on iOS 5, iOS 6 and iOS 6.1 simulators, but it doesn't work on iOS 6 devices

Comment: it seems this had something to do with the problem too, if I use region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerLocation, 800000, 800000); the region is the same before and after the view load, at least on the simulator. I'll wait until I receive my iPad retina with iOS6 to continue testing this issue. If I use region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerLocation, 0, 800000); the region is different if I use it before, and zoomed after.

Answer (score 1):

on ios 5 you have mapkit using google maps and ios 6 you have mapkit using built-in maps , there are likely to be differences -- especially visual wise

Comment: Mapkit is in both of them. Mapkit on iOS 5 uses google maps, and on iOS 6 uses apple maps, but it is mapkit on both. And the strange thing is, the map region (or zoom level) is shown properly on emulators, but not on iOS 6 devices

Comment: pedantic :D but you are right... I meant the right thing though, anyways edited my answer

Comment: LOL, sorry for that, but it might be confusing with the new google maps sdk, I just wanted to make clear that I'm using mapkit and the same code on both versions, the old one and the update. It still doesn't help me much, I can't understand why apple maps show different regions or zoom levels than the real devices